# How to make a dynamic ascii horizontal divider?

Tags: javascript, css, divider

In place of something like a horizontal rule or div border, I'd like to do something like this:

My Title
/*----------------------*/
My content

Notice how the divider between the Title and content is literally a slash, asterix, dashes, and then an asterix and slash to end (it's supposed to look like code).

I'm curious how I could achieve this effect on a fluid layout, with the divider stretching to fill the whole width of the div.  Also, I'd like to not use any art for this.  Just using ascii would be perfect.

Summary:  How can I create a dynamically resizing custom ascii divider?  I'm pressuming this will probably have to be done mostly in Javascript and then polling the width of the div everytime the window is resized, and then calculating the length of characters (it's a monospace font) required to fill that space.  Is this on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a great question, had a lot fun messing around making this CSS only solution.

(This needs to be tweaked for each new font family due differences in kerning but it should hold up reasonably well at different font sizes of the same family.)

```css
hr {
  /* reset */
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  
  /* sizing */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1em;
  
  /* dashes */
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%, transparent 80%); /* space */
  background-size: 0.4em 0.4em; /* dash */
  
  /* spacing between start/end */
  padding: 0 0.7em;
  background-clip: content-box;

  /* anchor ::before/::after */
  position: relative;
}


/* start/end */
hr::before,
hr::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5em;
}
hr::before {
  content: '/*';
  left: -0.1em;
}
hr::after {
  content: '*/';
  right: -0.1em;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Editable demo: [http://jsbin.com/tefuli/2](http://jsbin.com/tefuli/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Just realized you were asking for a solution that expands to the full width so I removed the arbitrary fixed width I’d set on my demo above.

Comment: Thanks!  This was great.  I had to do a little tweaking because if you set to 100% width, then the hr::after content pushes outside of the div.  So setting the width to something like 90% helped keep the "*/", from pushing outside of the right edge of the div.  Also, inside my hr::after I included a "\a" inside of the content parameter, and added white-space: pre.  This apparently forces a line break after the HR.  Since it's not technically "100%" width with my fix I needed a way to make sure things line broke properly after the <hr>.  Thanks!

Comment: Heh, for the issue with `::after` pushing outside the div, any chance you copied this before I edited my answer to add `box-sizing: border-box`? I saw that issue when I added `width: 100%` earlier this afternoon and fixed it above.

Comment: The reason the `::after` was jutting out is because by default the padding property tacks onto the width of the element. So if you make something `width: 100%` then give it any left/right padding the new width of the element will be 100%+any padding. *This is widely regarded as pretty daft on the part of the CSS spec writers.* `box-sizing` is a CSS property that allows you to change those rules as to what affects the sizing of CSS elements. More info on it here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing

Comment: Yah it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have padding extend the boundaries of an object.  Thanks Zaqx.  Appreciate the extra info!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible without using JavaScript with the `white-space` CSS property:

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
#dashes {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#opencomment, #dashes, #closecomment {
  position: absolute;
}
#opencomment, #closecomment {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 10;
}
#closecomment {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    
    <div id='opencomment'>/*</div>
    <div id='dashes'>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</div>
    <div id='closecomment'>*/</div>

    <!-- position:absolute elements don't affect the DOM, so we need to
        "clear a line" -->
    <div>&nbsp;</div>

    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

I just used an absurd amount of dashes in order to fill up wide screens. You can change the width of `#container` in order to make it wider or narrower, or you could remove the `#container` element entirely.

Comment: Both really cool answers.  I choose the other one because I will be using this HR in many different places and I didn't want to have to include that "long dash line" in every place.  The biggest advantage for this method though is if you cannot re-create the dashes using the css linear gradient tool, then this will match the dashes perfectly.